# How to reset a mysql table column through php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a restaurant managment program. I have a table `order_header` in mysql, made with phpmyadmin, that looks like this:

```
OrderID | TableID | Date | UserID | Sum
```

The `sum` is the sum of each order, and if I add the sums of all orders I get the current money in the cash desk.

How to reset the whole sum column using php, so I can reset the cash desk? I tried doing that using a form with a post method but I failed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with **clearly** stating what your desired result is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to reset the `sum` column, rather than just delete all the orders?

Comment: `UPDATE order_header SET sum = 0` will set them all to zero.